# Azure: Listening on non default ports gives access denied

Tags: c#, azure, networking, port, azure-webjobs

I trying to run a simple webjob that essentially opens ports and listens on them for traffic.  I want to be able to use a different port that 80 or 443.  My code is:

```
var listeningOn = string.Format("http://wwwmydomain.com:4027,
            var appHost = new AppHost();
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start(listeningOn);
```

As soon as I start the AppHost I get an error stating:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is
>   denied [10/06/2015 15:04:49 > ccdf79: ERR ]    at
>   System.Net.HttpListener.SetupV2Config() [10/06/2015 15:04:49 > ccdf79:
>   ERR ]    at System.Net.HttpListener.Start() [10/06/2015 15:04:49 >
>   ccdf79: ERR ]    at
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.HttpListenerBase.Start(String
>   urlBase)

Is there any way around this or is my only option to use a VM.  I had looked into Azure traffic management but this didn't really seem to suit my needs. There are internal reasons I need to use port 4027 which are outside of my control.

Comment: Is this for Azure Web App? I don't understand the relationship to WebJobs?

Comment: I've created an Azure WebApp, inside the web app I've added a WebJob. The WebJob is just an .exe, I've updated my post to make that clearer.

Comment: WebJobs can't listen on arbitrary ports, but we do have a new project that will let you have them listen for requests. Take a look at David's post below.

Answer (score 5):

When running Node on Azure Web Apps, you cannot listen on arbitrary ports. Instead, you can only listen on `process.env.PORT`. This is actually set to a named pipe rather than a port, but that's more of an implementation detail.

Comment: It's not node, It's a c# console application, it's running as a webjob in a WebApp

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the C# code snippet. But in any case, the restriction is the same that you can't just start listening on an arbitrary port. We do have an upcoming WebJobs feature that lets a WebJobs handle web hooks, effectively processing http traffic (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions). This may not be what you're after though.

Comment: Thanks David, there may be something in that of use. The application essentially opens a TCP connection and listens for data from client applications which are installed in various LANs, it then forwards any data it receives to another client which contains the UI.